# Why am I not seeing anything for IE 8.0 for the following page?

Tags: html, xhtml, dhtml

http://havanasanjuan.com/

FF seems fine.I know this is something trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The woman is too hot for IE! :)

Seriously though, the JPEG was saved in the [CMYK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK) colour space. Internet Explorer can deal with RGB images only. You should change the colour space in your graphics application if you can, or select it when exporting, or use the program's "prepare for web" tool if it has one.

And the image *is* a bit big btw. 1.2 MB is much more than necessary. I can get it compressed to 200-300 kilobytes without any notable loss in quality.

Comment: Thank You. It was bad creatives sent to me. I should have thought of that. Thanks again.